# Why can't I access the internet when using static ip in a vm? (Netplan)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, netplan, nat

I'm trying to configure a network like this using VMs:

[image: network plan picture]

For this I have to configure a NatNetwork in virtualbox. Here is the configuration:

[image: NatNetwork config]

As you can see DHCP support is unmarked.

Now. I try to configure the first PC (Ubuntu Desktop) using the following configuration of netplan:

[image: netplan not working]

I do `sudo netplan update` annnnd...

[image: interrogation sign]

As you can see the internet is unreachable and it shows wired connected with an interrogation sign.

Here is an image showing that the changes applied correctly:

[image: network tests1]

Now... I change dhcp in netplan from no to yes...

[image: new netplan config]

`sudo netplan apply` ... and suddenly:

[image: internet working]

Everything works for some reason. Can access the internet normally.

Here are the same tests I did before and you'll see that everything is literally the same.

[image: network test 2]

I don't understand why it works when DHCP is enabled and it does not when disabled. Considering the natnetwork does not even support DHCP.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Check https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#networkingdetails .

Answer (score 1):

I see while you are making it static still it does  ping its gateway,
So, most probably of the issue is cause of DNS, set the DNS also.

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf
```

In case you want to add DNS in netplan:

```
> nameservers:
>         addresses:
>         - 8.8.8.8
>         - 1.0.0.1
```

Comment: It would be better to do this in netplan, since that is what is being used.  Editing resolv.conf directly will be a temporary solution at best.

Comment: No it is not temporary! if you still wants to add to netplan then you can add there too.

Comment: NetworkManager has connectivity checks beyond up routing, which include a dependency on DNS.  The original config had no DNS, and DHCP servers almost always provide DNS, so yes this is quite likely to be the issue

Comment: Multiple things including NetworkManager step on resolve.conf, so changes there will eventually be blanked if they are not added to netplan.